# How allow other user on skype to chat withou having then on the contact list using Skype4COM?

Tags: api, delphi, skype, skype4com

I'm trying chage a setting on other user on Skype, to allow then chat with other user without having then on Skype contact list by API on Delphi.

There`s a way to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, no.

There is `SKYPE4COMLib_TLB.pas` type library which you can use to interact with Skype. You have to import in Delphi (Tools > Import a Type Library > Skype4COM 1.0 Type Library). From what I've seen, it doesn't expose Privacy settings for the current user.